# Express 4 HTTP requests: user._id undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, get

I'm writing a simple Express app to handle image uploads and searches. The upload works fine but the same req.user._id is invalid in the get request. Any idea why?

```
//standard express-generator server.js requires
//passport.js implementation

 var session      = require('express-session');
 app.use(session({
   secret: '*****',
   proxy: true,
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
  }));
```

The post function **works fine using Multer middleware**. It uses req.user._id with no issues - I've checked that it's being uploaded to the database.

```
app.post('/upload/photoData', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res) {

    //Retrieve data from request using multer middleware objects
    var title = req.body.title;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var photoURL = req.file.filename;
    var date = new Date();
    var user_id = req.user._id;

    //Code to create Mongoose photo model instance using variables above and save


});
```

Immediately after I'm testing a get function that returns the following error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined**

```
app.get('/file/newCalendar', function(req, res) {

  var selectedDate = moment(req.query.m)//moment(req.query.m);
  var selectedMonth = selectedDate.month()//selectedDate.month();
  var user_idLookup = req.query.v;
    if(!user_idLookup){
      user_idLookup = req.user._id;
    };

    jsontest = {
      'selectedDate': selectedDate,
      'selectedMonth': selectedMonth,
      'user': user_idLookup
    };
})
```

Comment: Are you use express session?

Comment: Yes I am usingexpress session v1. Have edited the main post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel stupid now. req.user was not defined because I was manually submitting the GET request before signing in/serializing user!